# having an a submission issue with contact form

Tags: php, forms

i have a one input contact form for people to submit an email. i have created a php script to email me. every time i hit the Subscribe (submit button) i get the following error:
[Error that keeps being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GDA1.png)

> *Error: Form submission failed and no error message returned from*

I have tried check my file. I have created a new php file ][. I have also deleted my file
i am not sure what is causing the error. Could really use some help.

Comment: Check the logs to get the error details